# Why do variables change lines when writing to text files?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file which I read information off of as variables, as a saving system in my game. The problem is I need my document to read and write to a certain line, it works fine the first write and read, but the second time the line before it has moved up one and I get "Index out of range" Because line I'm trying to write/read is blank.

[image: First Read Write]

[image]

I've looked through my code and can't seem to find the problem..

```
gold=(60)
goldtxt=(str(gold) + 'gp')
inventory=['empty','empty','empty','empty','empty','empty','empty','empty','empty','empty',]

def ItemAdd(event):
   gamestatus = linecache.getline('C:Location', 2).rstrip() 
   if gamestatus == 'gamestatus1':       
      gameinfo1[7] = (inventory[(-1)]).strip('empty') + ' '
      gameinfo1[9] = goldtxt + '             '
      with open('C:Location', 'w') as active:
         active.writelines(gameinfo1) 
         RefreshTexts() 

def RefreshTexts():
    with open('C:Location', 'r') as file: 
        datatemplate = file.readlines() 
    with open('C:Location', 'r') as file: 
        gameinfo1 = file.readlines() 
    with open('C:Location', 'r') as file: 
        gameinfo2 = file.readlines() 
    with open('C:Location', 'r') as file: 
        gameinfo3 = file.readlines() 
    with open('C:Location', 'r') as file: 
        activeinfo = file.readlines()
```

I have a little over a thousand lines, but I think this is where the problem would lie should there be one.

Comment: Why couldn't you save your datastructure say as a [`JSON`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) file instead

Comment: You are either adding or removing newlines incorrectly

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I'm relatively new to python, so I have no experience working with .JSON files.

Comment: What is the logic behind all the `gameinfo...=`?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the error occurs either because you're using `rstrip` somewhere which strips the newline characters at the end of lines; or it could be that you're **ab**using `linecache`; even though Python 2 documentation says something about general linewise random access, in Python 3 the documentation clearly states that:

> The linecache module allows one to get any line **from a Python source file**, while attempting to optimize internally, **using a cache**, the common case where many lines are read from a single file. This is used by the traceback module to retrieve source lines for inclusion in the formatted traceback.

In any case using `linecache` is a very poor match for your use case, because `linecache` assumes that the files do not change, but your savefiles do change; and you're refreshing them after save. I'd recommend that you'd save and load your game state data to and from a single dictionary using the [`json.load`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) and [`json.dump`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump)

Something like:

```
import json

def save_game(game_data):
    with open('mysavedgame', 'w') as save_file:
        json.dump(game_data, save_file)

def load_game():
    with open('mysavedgame', 'r') as save_file:
        return json.load(save_file)

def new_game():
    return {
        'items': [],
        'money': 0
    }

# when starting a new game
game_data = new_game()

# adding items, money:
game_data['items'].append('Crystal sword')
game_data['money'] += 60

# when saving a game, use
save_game(game_data)

# and load the data with
game_data = load_game()
print(game_data)
```

Running the program prints

```
{'money': 60, 'items': ['Crystal sword']}
```

and the contents of `mysavegame` are

```
{"money": 60, "items": ["Crystal sword"]}
```

Comment: agreed that json is the right solution here. The strange behavior of these text files is just a symptom of the bad solution.